# Storing/restoring values from a class to/from a list of property names and values

Tags: c#, linq, collections

I am not sure what the best and simplest way to do this, so any advice is appreciated.

I want to get all the fields on any/all/single domain entity class and add prefix/remove prefix dynamically when calling a particular method.

For example, I have entities such as:

```
public class Shop
{
 public string TypeOfShop{get;set}
 public string OwnerName {get;set}
 public string Address {get;set}
}

public class Garage
{
 public string Company {get;set}
 public string Name {get;set}
 public string Address {get;set}
}
```

and so on...

I want to get a list of the properties with a prefix:

```
public Class Simple
{
    public class Prop
    {
     public string Name{get;set;}
     public string Value{get;set;}
    } 

    public ICollection list = new List<Prop>();

    //set all prop
    public void GetPropertiesWithPrefix(Garage mygarage, string prefix)
    {
     list.Add(new Prop{Name = prefix + "_Company", Value = mygarage.Company});
     //so on... upto 50 props...
    }

}

//to get this list I can simple call the list property on the Simple class
```

When reading each field I am using a switch statement and setting the value.

```
//Note I return a collection of Prop that have new values set within the view,lets say
//this is a result returned from a controller with the existing prop names and new values...

public MyGarage SetValuesForGarage(MyGarage mygarage, string prefix, ICollection<Prop> _props)
{

  foreach (var item in _prop)
  {
   switch(item.Name)
   {
     case prefix + "Company":
     mygarage.Company = item.Value;
     break;
     //so on for each property...

   }

  }

}
```

Is there a better, simpler or more elegant way to do this with linq or otherwise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could store props in a dictionary, then have:

```
mygarage.Company = _props[prefix + "_Company"];
mygarage.Address = _props[prefix + "_Address"];
//And so on...
```

in your `SetValuesForGarage` method instead of a loop with a `switch` inside.

**EDIT**

For more info on using `Dictionary` see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx).

You can define `list` something like:

```
Dictionary<string, string> list = new Dictionary<string, string>();
```

And have something like the following in your `GetPropertiesWithPrefix` method:

```
list.Add(prefix + "_Company", mygarage.Company);
list.Add(prefix + "_Address", mygarage.Address);
//And so on...
```

This would eliminate your `Prop` class.

Comment: This Prop class gets given to this method from the service layer, hence why I use it, I could .ToDictionary() this list but I am keeping in mind data checking + persisting, the above example takes care of setting the value but after this example I forget I needed validation, the thing is, even if I use a dictionary it is almost the same lines of code as the foreach loop and switch statement... In short it does not sound like there is a too better way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the following method works for you. It takes any object, looks up its properties and returns a list with your Prop objects, each for every property.

```
public class PropertyReader
{
    public static List<Prop> GetPropertiesWithPrefix(object obj, string prefix)
    {
        if (obj == null)
        {
            return new List<Prop>();
        }

        var allProps = from propInfo
                       in obj.GetType().GetProperties()
                       select new Prop()
                       {
                           Name = prefix + propInfo.Name,
                           Value = propInfo.GetValue(obj, null) as string
                       };
        return allProps.ToList();
    }
}
```